# Delete all files and directories from Command Prompt

Tags: windows-8, command-line

I have the following situation. I got a Temp folder which gets filled with all kinds of files and directories. I want/need to clean it regularly, but I can't figure out a command or set of MS-DOS command to do so.
Command called erase deletes all the files, so no problem there, but the directories is the thing I'm struggling with. I know some of you might suggest deleting the Temp directory and then creating it, which is NOT an option for me unfortunately, since I MUST keep it intact, since doing messes up things on my system.

Any ideas, good people? :)

Comment: Did you actually mean MS-DOS or did you mean Command Prompt within Windows?

Comment: Yessir, I very much did.

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702040/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-using-batch#answer-17720127

Answer (score 10):

In a MS-DOS system use `deltree`.

`DELTREE [/Y] directory\*.*`

From a cmd windows in the latest versions you can use `rd.exe` or `rmdir.exe`

`rd directory/* /s`

or

`rmdir directory/* /s`

Comment: Well, DELTREE is out of the question, since we're talking command promt in Winodws 8 basically. As for rd and rmdir, for some reason none of them does what I need. I mean, if I do rm/rmdir c:\q\* /s it 1) asks for a confirmation, which it should not because of /s 2) does nothing when I confirm it. Weird... Any other ideas, good people of SuperUser :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have it asking you for confirmation you need also the `/Q` switch

I have a batch file that does the following:

```
rmdir E:\Documents /s /q
```

I wanted it to delete the contents of the Documents folder but instead this command deletes the whole folder. I tried E:\Documents* but to no avail.

So what I ended up doing was:

```
rmdir E:\Documents\*.* /s /q
mkdir E:\Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@del /S /Q /F temp\* >nul
@for /d %%i in (temp\*) do @rmdir /s /q "%%i"
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.